# How to animate pacman?

Tags: c++, pacman

I am writing a pacman game in C++. I am trying to figure out a good way to switch between 2 images. Currently, If I move pacman with the keys the image changes to pacman image facing the right way which is good. But now when he continues to move in that direction, I need to switch between an open and closed mouth image. I was thinking to use a function that takes both images and switches between them but I am not sure what that would look like. The function to change the image is simple and looks like below(this function is called every time a different key is pressed up, down, left or right).

```
void Avatar::SetImage(const char* _image)
{
    myImage = _image;
}
```

Comment: Pass different images as arguments to `SetImage`.

Comment: But how do I go back and forth between 2 different images. This will also need to be done with a delay because doing it every frame would be too fast I think.

Comment: Use a counter like `counter = counter > 20 ? 0 : counter + 1; SetImage(image[counter / 10])` to change it every 10 frames.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, for this types of games, you have a game loop to check input, react to that input, set game states and render the graphics.

You'd naturally try to limit the speed the gameloop is run to something like 60 passes per second (or some other value).

You also probably want to track which frame is displayed currently.
You could use that information in your render part to decide, which graphic should be displayed.

A common way to do this is to use the modulo (%) operator.
You can modulo the frame counter to decide if the mouth open or mouth closed image should be displayed.

For example with 60 fps (pseudocode): `if (frame_counter % 60 < 30) {SetImage(Image1)} else{SetImage(Image2)}`